# Smartgit SHA fingerprint of the certificate does not match

Tags: bitbucket, sha, smartgit

I am trying to install SmartGit and trying to provide bitbucket as hosting provide. I provide correct credentials of my bitbucket account but I get following error:

=======================================

java.security.cert.CerfiticateException: SHA fingerprint of the certificate does not match.

Expected: [some string]
Actual: [some other string]

This may either mean that the server certificate has changed or that you are spoofed.

=======================================

I think this is related to SSL certificate but do not know how to fix it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From [1]: to fix SmartGit 5.0.7.1 (and older) add following line to smartgit.properties (in the SmartGit settings directory, see About dialog):

```
smartgit.hostingProvider.bitbucket.sslFingerprint=37:A8:0E:13:87:DA:13:C3:B8:35:6F:84:EF:74:D2:38:B1:AC:59:9B
```

After restarting SmartGit, connection will work again.

[1] http://blog.syntevo.com/2014/03/09/1394361360000.html

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Guess BitBucket changed their key since the latest version got released.
**Solution** (or rather, workaround)...:
Don't add BitBucket as a remote provider. Add your URL simply per each project.
`Remote` -> `Add`

You can find the URL for your projects on the web interface of BitBucket.
Right after you select a project of yours, a link is displayed on the right side of your screen. It starts with `https` ... That is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

BitBucket just changed their certificates, as [**announced on their blog**](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/03/06/ssl-certificates-are-changing/).

> On March 7th at 22:00 UTC, we’ll be updating our SSL certificates to replace ones that will be expiring soon. It’s likely that you won’t notice any changes and won’t need to take any action.

You can work around it it using the per-project URLs as described in Shiki's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to your ~/.smartgit/5/smartgit.properties
    smartgit.hostingProvider.bitbucket.sslFingerprint=7F:E2:6E:8F:0B:7F:3A:CD:6E:02:54:04:03:57:39:BD:D2:4B:CF:AE

Then re-try adding Bitbucket and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but for github and adding the fingerprint to smartgit.properties was not working.

**What did work** was updating to the latest build (last option in the Help menu).